# Pagination component being rendered on a parent component, which is rendered on two different views/pages in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pagination, react-props, conditional-rendering

Im using react and I am trying to render a pagination component at the bottom of a table. The issue is that the pagination component has a parent component(holdingsChart) that is rendered in two different pages/views, and I only want it to be displayed in one of the pages, (Stats page instead of Dashboard page).So the table is being rendered in both Stats page and Dashboard page, but I only want the pagination to show in the Stats page. I have tried to leverage props in the parent component of both views, setting `setpagination` to true in Stats page and false in Dashboard page. But it seems like since the ProfilePagination component is in the same component that is being utilized accross both views, it doesnt make a differnce. So the pagination will always be present on both, or be absent from both. Its always following each other. Please see code snippet below and let me know if there are any other way to do this.

Sorry if it was a bit difficult to understand. It is pretty complicated to explain

Comment: What do you mean by `present on both, or be absent from both`? With the code you post in the answer, are the 2 present or absent?

Comment: They are present on both pages. Its tough because they are sharing the component. Sorry if its a bit confusing

Comment: everything LGTM, although you are repeating the logic for hiding the pagination in HoldingsChart and PortfolioPagination, the conditional render is not necessary for HoldingChart since you're doing the same inside PortfolioPagination. I recommend you to debug the component's props using react dev tools to see what is passed down https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-debug-react-components-using-react-developer-tools